# Error Handling in AngularJs and servlets

Tags: angularjs, servlets

I am currently working on some project where I am writing UI code in angularjs. 
I am stuck at framing the error handling.

The scenario is: I am writing some forms in angularJS. inside the controller I am making several $http calls which eventually call the servlets defined.

I need to notify the user about the success/failure of the servlets.

How can I achieve this?

Also, how can I handle the errors in this scenario?

For ex. when I submit the form below function gets executed:

```
`$scope.submitForm = function(form) {    
            console.log("--> Submitting form");
            if(confirm("Are you sure to finish?")){
                $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : '/XMLParser',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data    : JSON.stringify($scope.form), //forms user object
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
                }).success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.errors) {
                        // Showing errors.
                        $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                        $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.username;
                        $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
                    } else {
                        $scope.message = data.message;
                    }
                    alert("successful");
                });             
                $scope.redirectToHome();
            }           
        };`
```

The servlet /XMLParser will either successfully executed or may produce some errors. How can I handle those?

Comment: show us some code

Comment: javascript is not java.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hope this could make sense 
$http.get('your api url').then(success, failure);

function success(){
//your code when request respond success
};

function failure(){
//your code when request respond failure 
};
```

Comment: Or please refer this document http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/